# In context click and edit: is it feasible?

Tags: visual-editor, html-editor, customization

I would like the following feature, and I'm willing to put my hands on it, but I'd like that developers more in touch with WP codebase give me some feedback.

I want to have some sort of **in-context click-and-edit**. A typical scenario: I'm reading my own blog (I'm logged on) and I find some typo in a long post; instead of the common flow (scroll for the "edit post" link, then in the editor look for the offending word...) I'd like to (say) double click on the word and then the editor opens positioned on that word (or at least near it - say, in the same line of the raw HTML).
In my particular case, more than typos, what matters to me is the ability to make little and frecuent retouching of long texts more confortably.

(BTW: this would be similar in motivation of what the inmensely useful [synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/what-exactly-is-synctex) does for Latex: click on the produced PDF and jump to the code)

To accomplish this, we'd need

A. some way of coding the "current position" and pass it to the edit URL

B. that the editor (Visual and/or HTML) can process it, scrolling and positioning the caret

To implement A, I could consider (though I'm not sure if it's necessary) the in "logged mode" the post output includes some extra marking (eg, lots of empty  to signal the original line). I'm more concerned with B.

Any thoughts or pointers? Has something like this been implemented, or attemped or discussed?

Comment: There are some plugins out there that allows you to edit post blogs on the front end.